# Calculating the matrix exponential of the standard basis "vector" $E_{ij}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponential-function

I want to find out what $e^{E_{ij}}$ equals, where $E_{ij}$ is the $(i,j)$-th matrix in the standard basis of $M_n(\mathbb C)$.

It seems that in the case that $i\ne j$ we have that:
$$e^{E_{ij}}= I + \frac{E_{ij}}{1}+0+\cdots = I + E_{ij}$$

and in the case that $i=j$ we find that:
\begin{align}
E_{ii}^k=E_{ii}&\implies e^{E_{ii}}=I + E_{ii}+\frac{E_{ii}}{2}+\cdots\\
&\implies e^{E_{ii}}= I+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{E_{ii}}{n!}\\
&\implies e^{E_{ii}}=(e-1)E_{ii}+I.
\end{align}

Is that correct?

Comment: yes, thats correct.

Comment: I've modified your question. $E_{ij}$ is *not* an [elementary matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix), but a member of the standard basis of the matrix space $M_n(\mathbb C)$ or $M_n(\mathbb R)$.